# Keep running other functions after return in GraphQL resolvers

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

How can I keep other operation running after return in GraphQL resolvers.

packages

```
import { ApolloServer } from "@apollo/server";
import { typeDefs } from "./definitions";
import { resolvers } from "./resolvers";
import { makeExecutableSchema } from "graphql-tools";
import { applyMiddleware } from "graphql-middleware";
import { shield, allow } from "graphql-shield";
import { permissions } from "./shield/permissions";
```

Code

```
createOrder: async (_: any, args: MutationCreateOrderArgs, ctx: IContext) => {

const sendToGoogleSheetsPromise....
const sendToConversionApiPrmise....

return ctx.order.create()
}
```

Promises somehow got cancelled after return, I don't want to wait all of them or using Promise.all.

Is there something like `waitUntil()` in service workers?